# File upload fails using Blazor client, but succeeds using swagger/postman

Tags: c#, .net, file, blazor-webassembly

I have a file controller in .NET 6 application server and I wanted to upload files using Blazor-written client

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("AddFile")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> AddFile([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
        {return Ok();
}
```

and this the method executed on Blazor side

```
[Parameter]
public int id { get; set; }
private string title = string.Empty;
private DeviceHistoryReadOnlyDto DevicesHistory = new();
private Response<DeviceHistoryReadOnlyDto> response = new Response<DeviceHistoryReadOnlyDto> { Success = true };
private DeviceHistoryUpdateDto DeviceHistoryUpdate = new();
private Response<int> UpdateHistoryResponse = new Response<int> { Success = true };
//private FileUpdateDto fileUpdate = new();
private Response<int> fileResponse = new Response<int> { Success = true };
private Modal xlModal = default!;
private string bfile = string.Empty;
private bool edit = false;
private bool sUser = false;
private string desc = string.Empty;
private string user = string.Empty;
private List<string> filesToDel = new List<string>();
private int maxAllowedFiles = int.MaxValue;
private long maxFileSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
private MultipartFormDataContent? content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StringContent(id.ToString()), "idDHP");

    foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
    {
        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize))
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            content.Add(
                content: fileContent,
                name: "\"files\"",
                fileName: file.Name
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.OpenReadStreamAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.CopyFileDataIntoBuffer(Int64 sourceOffset, Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|29_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.SerializeToStreamAsyncCore(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at ServiceApp.Blazor.Server.UI.Pages.Urzadzenia.DeviceHistory.Save()
```

All other requests from different controllers are working fine. And the timeout error appears instantly after it hits PostAsync.
What am I doing wrong?

If I am passing null instead of content in the save method which is executed on button click it enters the controller otherwise it does not

```
 private async Task Save()
    {
        UpdateHistoryResponse = await deviceHistoryService.Put(id, new DeviceHistoryUpdateDto
            {
                Id = DevicesHistory.Id,
                Description = desc
            });
        
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7039");
            var data = await client.PostAsync("/api/File/AddFile", content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e}");
        }
        
        if (UpdateHistoryResponse.Success && fileResponse.Success)
        {
            await Cancel();
        }
    }
```